# Built Unity project, MySQL database isn't opened

Tags: c#, mysql, database, visual-studio, unity-game-engine

When I run my project in the Unity Editor, I can run my database. I can read and write to it with no issues. However when I build my project and run it, at the point where my database is read nothing happens.
I have set it up to create a text file when the database is read to check if it is read, but the text file is not created. From this I can assume that the database connection wasn't opened.
I am using a MySQL database that is in LocalHost. 
Is there a way of putting a database in the project files so that is accessible wherever the program is (e.g. on another computer), and to make this database readable? As if it were a textfile. This would be all I need. The database has a number of tables and all of them are accesed from my C# scripts when the game is running.
I do have a password for the connection but I haven't included it in the code below.
I need a really simple solution because data is only needed locally for the player's progress to be stored so there doesn't need to be a server hosting it if possible.

```
public string location = @"server=localhost;user=root;database=wattsup;port=3306;Allow User Variables=True"; //Path to database

    MySqlConnection con = new MySqlConnection(location);
    con.Open();
    MySqlCommandBuilder cmdBuilder = new MySqlCommandBuilder();
    string tbname = cmdBuilder.QuoteIdentifier(name1);
    string query = "SELECT Question FROM " + tbname + " WHERE ID = @value";
    MySqlCommand command = new MySqlCommand(query, con);
    command.Parameters.AddWithValue("@value", Equations[EquationValue].EquationID);
    MySqlDataReader reader = command.ExecuteReader();
    while (reader.Read())
    {
        SpaceGame.question = Convert.ToString(reader[0]);
        string fileName = @"Question.txt";
        //text file created to show me whether it is opened or not
        using (StreamWriter fileStream = File.CreateText(fileName))
        {
            fileStream.WriteLine(SpaceGame.question);
        }
    }
    con.Close();
```

Comment: Other than it would be a bit extreme for a game to install mysql just to store a players progress, I would add a bunch of logging for your game - what exactly are you building for windows? linux? mac? webgl? android?

Answer (score 0):

If you want to store the data in single file, maybe you can try `SQLite`. The following is the steps that using `SQLite` you can refer to.

1.Install System.Data.SQLite using `NuGet Package Manager`.

2.Configure the connection string in `App.config`

```html
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<configuration>
...
  <connectionStrings>
     <add name="SQLiteDbContext" connectionString="Data Source=MyDatabase.sqlite" providerName="System.Data.SQLite.EF6" />
  </connectionStrings>
</configuration>
```

3.The simple demo that create `.sqlite`.

```
// create
SQLiteConnection.CreateFile("MyDatabase.sqlite");

SQLiteConnection m_dbConnection = new SQLiteConnection("Data Source=MyDatabase.sqlite");
m_dbConnection.Open();

string sql = "create table highscores (name varchar(20), score int)";

SQLiteCommand command = new SQLiteCommand(sql, m_dbConnection);
command.ExecuteNonQuery();

sql = "insert into highscores (name, score) values ('Me', 9001)";

command = new SQLiteCommand(sql, m_dbConnection);
command.ExecuteNonQuery();// read
SQLiteCommand sqlCom = new SQLiteCommand("Select * From highscores", m_dbConnection);

SQLiteDataReader sqlDataReader = sqlCom.ExecuteReader();

int i = 1;
while (sqlDataReader.Read())
{
    listBox1.Items.Add(i);
    listBox1.Items.Add(sqlDataReader.GetValue(0));
    listBox1.Items.Add(sqlDataReader.GetValue(1));
    i++;
}

m_dbConnection.Close();
```